# Calculation of time intervals using 'lubridate'

Tags: r, lubridate

For statistical reasons, I would like to calculate the following:

date2 - date1 +1(day) ; in month.

For the above equation, this shall mean 1 day if date2 == date1.
For data, time data is only available for Y,M,D (no HH,MM).
The date below is available for demo.

```
date <- as.POSIXct("2009-03-08")
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2009-03-09")
```

I would like to get

```
( (date %--% date2)+1 )/ months(1)
```

(But this doesn’t work)

( (date %--% date2)+1 )/ days(1)
gives me 2 (days).
Now, I would like to calculate this value to month.
How can I achieve this?
Or rather, can I go straightforward,
like below equation?
( (date %--% date2)+1 )/ months(1)

Comment: I am unclear about what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean by you want to calculate the value to month?

Comment: Do the spaces in `(date %--% date2)+1 / months(1)` imply anything? `((date %--% date2)+1) / months(1)` or `(date %--% date2) + (1/months(1))`?

Comment: What would be some sample input and output for "to month"?

Comment: I edited my question. ((date %--% date2)+1) / months(1) is what I meant Thank you @PeterMortensen

Comment: I need something like {(date1 %--% date2)/days(1) +1}/months(1) @Joon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### First edition (Deprecated)

`date %--% date2` is a `<Interval>`. You cannot add a numeric value to it. Instead, you need to convert it into a `<Period>`.

```r
(as.period(date %--% date2) + days(1)) / months(1)

# [1] 0.06570842
```

---

##### Update

The above method is not precise because it cannot take months into account. The ideal output should be

```r
(1 + 1) / 31
# [1] 0.06451613
```

becasue **March** has *31* days. The following way is able to consider the differences of days between different months.

```r
(date %--% (date2 + days(1))) / months(1)
# [1] 0.06451613
```

For comparison, we change the dates to **February** and see the output:

```r
date <- as.POSIXct("2009-02-08")
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2009-02-09")

(date %--% (date2 + days(1))) / months(1)
# [1] 0.07142857
```

which is equal to `(1 + 1)/28`.

Comment: @D.Shin my first answer is not precise. Please check my update.

Comment: Thank you for being precise,
But I get this message : Incompatible classes: <IDate> + <Period>
I think the problem why I'm struggling is my real data is IDate
Shall I fix my question @Darren

Comment: @D.Shin `IDate` is an object from `data.table`? If it's incompatible to `lubridate`, you should convert those `IDate` columns into `Date` or `POSIXct` supported by `lubridate`.

Comment: @D.Shin Try `(date %--% (as.Date(date2) + days(1))) / months(1)`

Answer (score 1):

The `difftime` command in base R subtracts one date from another. Unfortunately, it does not have the option to return the output in months; however, if we choose days, we can manually convert it.

#### Base

```
date1 <- as.POSIXct("2009-03-08")
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2009-03-09")
    
(1 + as.numeric(difftime(time1 = date2,time2 = date1,units = "days")))/30.4375
```

#### lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
date1 <- ymd("2009-03-08")
date2 <- ymd("2009-03-09")

(1 + as.numeric(date2 - date1))/30.4375
```

#### Output

```
[1] 0.06570842
```

Comment: But can we do it using lubridate?

Comment: I don't know a direct way to do it, but I updated my solution also using lubridate

Comment: Take `30.4375` is not precise. The example dates are on March, so the expected output should be `(1+1) / 31` = `0.064516`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to divide the 2 dates by 30.4375 which is obtained from 365.25/12

### Code

```r
data.frame(date1=date, date2=date2) %>% mutate(date1=as.Date(date1),
                                                        date2=as.Date(date2),
                                                        diff=(date1-date2)/30.4375)
```

Comment: Re *"Please try"*: What is the idea?

Comment: like in my answer, i tried to convert the date and date2 to proper date format using as.Date. then took the difference between the dates by diving with 30.4375 which results in the difference of dates in months. Please let me know if this isn't something you are expecting

Comment: Take `30.4375` is not precise. The example dates are on March, so the expected output should be `(1+1) / 31` = `0.064516`.